# How to prevent conflict in wire value in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I am designing a SPI device which has a master and 3 slaves. When I try to send data from master to one slave on MOSI, it works fine.  But when I send a sequence of bits from a slave to a master on MISO, I get a lot of Xs. I know that this happens due to a conflict in values in the wire, but I can't solve it.

Here is the code:

```
module Master(dataIN,dataOUT,slaveno,enable,reset,cpha,cpol,miso,mosi,clk,cs0,cs1,cs2);

  input enable,reset,cpha,cpol,miso,clk;
  output reg mosi,cs0,cs1,cs2;
  input [1:0] slaveno;
  input [7:0] dataIN;
  output [7:0] dataOUT;

  integer mode = 0;

  reg [7:0] data;

  assign dataOUT = data;

  always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
      if (reset)
        begin
          data <= 8'b00000000; 
          cs0 <= 1'b1;
          cs1 <= 1'b1;
          cs2 <= 1'b1;
          mosi <= 1'b0;
        end
        else if (enable === 1) begin
        case(slaveno)    
          2'b00    : cs0 <= 1'b0;
          2'b01    : cs1 <= 1'b0;
          2'b10    : cs2 <= 1'b0; 
          2'b11    : begin
            cs0 <= 1'b1;
            cs1 <= 1'b1;
            cs2 <= 1'b1;  
          end  
          default  : begin
            cs0 <= 1'b1;
            cs1 <= 1'b1;
            cs2 <= 1'b1;  
          end  
        endcase
        if (cpha === 1'b0 && cpol === 1'b0) 
            mode = 1;
          else if (cpha === 1'b0 && cpol === 1'b1)
            mode = 0;
          else if (cpha === 1'b1 && cpol === 1'b0)
            mode = 0;
          else if (cpha === 1'b1 && cpol === 1'b1)
            mode = 1;
        case (mode)
        0 : mosi <= data[7];
        1 : begin
          data [7:1] <= data [6:0];          
          data [0] <= miso;      
        end
        endcase
      end
      else if (enable === 1'b0 && dataIN !== 1'b0) begin
        data <= dataIN;
        cs0 <= 1'b1;
        cs1 <= 1'b1;
        cs2 <= 1'b1;
      end
    end

  always @ (negedge clk)
    begin
      if (reset)
        begin
          data <= 8'b00000000; 
          cs0 <= 1'b1;
          cs1 <= 1'b1;
          cs2 <= 1'b1;
          mosi <= 1'b0;
        end
        else if (enable === 1'b1) begin   
        case(slaveno)
          2'b00    : cs0 <= 1'b0;
          2'b01    : cs1 <= 1'b0;
          2'b10    : cs2 <= 1'b0;
          2'b11    : begin
            cs0 <= 1'b1;
            cs1 <= 1'b1;
            cs2 <= 1'b1;  
          end
          default  : begin
            cs0 <= 1'b1;
            cs1 <= 1'b1;  
            cs2 <= 1'b1;  
          end  
        endcase
        if (cpha === 1'b0 && cpol === 1'b0) 
            mode = 1;
          else if (cpha === 1'b0 && cpol === 1'b1)
            mode = 0;
          else if (cpha === 1'b1 && cpol === 1'b0)
            mode = 0;
          else if (cpha === 1'b1 && cpol === 1'b1)
            mode = 1;
        case (mode)
        0 : begin
          data [7:1] <= data [6:0];
          data [0] <= miso;      
        end
        1 : mosi <= data[7];
        endcase  
      end
      else if (enable === 1'b0 && dataIN !== 1'b0) begin
        data <= dataIN;
        cs0 <= 1'b1;
        cs1 <= 1'b1;
        cs2 <= 1'b1;
      end
    end
endmodule

module Slave(slaveDataIN,slaveDataOUT,reset,cpha,cpol,miso,mosi,clk,cs);

  input reset,cpha,cpol,mosi,clk,cs;
  output reg miso;
  input [7:0] slaveDataIN;
  output [7:0]  slaveDataOUT;

  reg [7:0] data;

  integer mode = 0;

  assign  slaveDataOUT = data;

  always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
      if (reset)
        begin
        data <= 8'b00000000;
        miso <= 1'b0;
      end
      else if (cs === 1'b0) begin
        if (cpha === 1'b0 && cpol === 1'b0)
          mode = 1;
        else if (cpha === 1'b0 && cpol === 1'b1)
          mode = 0;
        else if (cpha === 1'b1 && cpol === 1'b0)
          mode = 0;
        else if (cpha === 1'b1 && cpol === 1'b1)
          mode = 1;
        case (mode)
          1 : miso <= data[7];
          0 : begin
            data [7:1] <= data [6:0];
            data [0] <= mosi;
          end
        endcase
      end
      else if (cs === 1'b1 && slaveDataIN !== 1'b0)
        data <= slaveDataIN;
    end

  always @ (negedge clk)
    begin
      if (reset)
        begin
        data <= 8'b00000000;
        miso <= 1'b0;
      end
      else if (cs === 1'b0) begin
        if (cpha === 1'b0 && cpol === 1'b0)
          mode = 1;
        else if (cpha === 1'b0 && cpol === 1'b1)
          mode = 0;
        else if (cpha === 1'b1 && cpol === 1'b0)
          mode = 0;
        else if (cpha === 1'b1 && cpol === 1'b1)
          mode = 1;
        case (mode)
          1 : begin
            data [7:1] <= data [6:0];
            data [0] <= mosi;
          end
          0 : miso <= data[7];
        endcase
      end
      else if (cs === 1'b1 && slaveDataIN !== 1'b0)
        data <= slaveDataIN;
    end
endmodule

module SPI(masterDataIN,slave0DataIN,slave1DataIN,slave2DataIN,masterDataOUT,slave0DataOUT,
            slave1DataOUT,slave2DataOUT,slaveno,enable,reset,cpha,cpol,clk);

input [7:0] masterDataIN,slave0DataIN,slave1DataIN,slave2DataIN;
output wire [7:0] masterDataOUT,slave0DataOUT,slave1DataOUT,slave2DataOUT;
input [1:0] slaveno;
input enable,reset,cpha,cpol,clk;
wire miso,mosi,cs0,cs1,cs2;

Master m (masterDataIN,masterDataOUT,slaveno,enable,reset,cpha,cpol,miso,mosi,clk,cs0,cs1,cs2);
Slave s1 (slave0DataIN,slave0DataOUT,reset,cpha,cpol,miso,mosi,clk,cs0);
Slave s2 (slave1DataIN,slave1DataOUT,reset,cpha,cpol,miso,mosi,clk,cs1);
Slave s3 (slave2DataIN,slave2DataOUT,reset,cpha,cpol,miso,mosi,clk,cs2);
endmodule
```

In the testbench, I try to put data in `slaveDataIN` and receive it on `masterDataOUT` after 8 cycles (I get most of it in Xs).  How do I solve this conflict?

PS: The x appears in place of 1 only not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a separate wire for each slave's MISO signal, then use a control signal like `slaveno` to select which slave drives the `miso` input to the master.  For example:

```
wire miso1, miso2, miso3;

assign miso = (slaveno == 0) ? miso1 : (slaveno == 1) ? miso2 : miso3;

Slave s1 (slave0DataIN,slave0DataOUT,reset,cpha,cpol, miso1, mosi,clk,cs0);
Slave s2 (slave1DataIN,slave1DataOUT,reset,cpha,cpol, miso2, mosi,clk,cs1);
Slave s3 (slave2DataIN,slave2DataOUT,reset,cpha,cpol, miso3, mosi,clk,cs2);
                                                         //
```

---

PS.  In your code, if all 3 slaves drive `miso`=0, then there will be no contention since they are all the same value; that explains why you see 0, not x.